# How to allow all system users (old and created in future) to start docker images and build them?

Tags: docker

How to allow all system users (old and created in future) to start docker images and build them? Currently I see only per user add to `docker` group which is extreamly inconvinient...

Answer (score 0):

See `/etc/adduser.conf` to add default user groups:

```
# Set this if you want the --add_extra_groups option to adduser to add
# new users to other groups.
# This is the list of groups that new non-system users will be added to
# Default:
#EXTRA_GROUPS="dialout cdrom floppy audio video plugdev users"

# If ADD_EXTRA_GROUPS is set to something non-zero, the EXTRA_GROUPS
# option above will be default behavior for adding new, non-system users
#ADD_EXTRA_GROUPS=1
```